# I can't enter a big decimal number in Excel

Tags: python, export-to-excel

I am using Python and I use this method to enter numbers in an Excel sheet:

```
file_loc = "C:/Users/mahmoud/Desktop/Book1.xlsx"
new_sheet = pyexcel.get_sheet(file_loc)
new_sheet.row += [2, 'Series2', 'Possible', 25.00000000000000004, 0]
new_sheet.save_as(file_loc)
```

My problem is that it doesn't enter `25.00000000000000004` in the Excel sheet but when I open it enters `25` instead.
But when I decrease the number of decimal points a bit to `25.000004` it enters it normally as it is.

Is there a way I can enter `25.00000000000000004` in the Excel sheet as it is so that I can use it later?

Comment: when you say "when I open it," do you mean when you open excel?  or when you open the excel file using python and extract the data?  either way, my guess is there's a limit to the number of decimal positions that can be stored.  do you really need such fine precision?

Comment: @dbliss oh sorry it wasn't clear I apologize but I meant when I open the excel file manually and see what's written in that row but yea I guess I need some kind of precision but not to that 15 decimal places extend.

Answer (score 4):

Based on excel's specification, the number precision is limited to 15 digits.  The number you listed has 18 digits of precision.
https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Comment: @pnuts i don't see that as a great solution, as it prevents him from being able to perform mathematical operations on the data within excel.

Comment: @pnuts you think it's possible to get more than 15-point precision with mathematical operations in Excel by storing the numbers as strings?  regarding your second point, of course i wasn't suggesting that the OP use `pandas` to enter numbers into Excel.  i was suggesting that the OP use `pandas` instead of Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Excel's 8-byte floating point numbers doesn't allow for more than [15 significant digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel), and your example has 19.

If you don't need to perform math operations on them, then put quotes around it in Python and treat it like a text string instead.  VBA can handle more decimal places with some of its 12-byte decimal types, so you may be able to convert the string to a number within VBA and return whatever result you need as a string again.

Comment: What is VBA?
And yes I guess have to use that because I have to get this [25.0000.....4,0] 
and another point which is [25,0] which are coordinates of points and calculate the distance between them so when I extract the [25.0000....4,0] from excel it becomes 25 and so the distance is 0 and not 0.00000.....4 like I want.

Comment: why not just do what you need to do using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) within python?

Comment: Right - if the portion to the right of the decimal is always small, then you can split up the math problem in Excel, dealing with 25 (2 signiticant digits) separate from .0000000000000000004 (1 significant digit) and recombine them later as a string, but this only works if the decimal portion won't exceed the same limitation.  Numbers like 25.12345678901234567 would still break it using this method.

Comment: @Mahmoud Ayman, VBA is Visual Basic for Applications - the integrated programming system that you can use to program Excel and many other products.